# why does my UISlider not match up to the value I gave it when i load my simulator

Tags: swift, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeb5T.jpg)

I do not understand why my height and weight slider are not in the middle when i load the simulator as I set the value to be 1.5 and 100 respectively; which is the middle of the minimum and maximum values of both values.

Comment: Read the doc for `UISlider`.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider

Comment: Have you tried with a comma? So 1,5 instead of 1.5.